# Weird results with WMI query for logged in users

Tags: .net, powershell, wmi

all!

I'm trying to execute a pretty common WMI query for getting a list of users logged into any given machine. It is shown below (using Powershell code):

```
 $wmi_result = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT LogonId FROM Win32_LogonSession WHERE LogonType=2" 
 foreach ($obj in $wmi_result) {
      $id = $obj.LogonId
      $user_list = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=$id} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" | Select Name
 }
```

This works perfectly well on my local machine, but gives me nothing on remote machines. However, I'm able to get this information pretty readily if I manually parse the Dependent property of the associated class, as shown below:

```
 $wmi_result = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT LogonId FROM Win32_LogonSession WHERE LogonType=2" -ComputerName <computer>
 foreach ($obj in $wmi_result) {
      $id = $obj.LogonId
      $user_list = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LoggedOnUser" | where {$_.Dependent -match $id} -ComputerName <computer>
      foreach ($path in $user_list) {
            $user = ([wmi]$path).name
      }
 }
```

I've tried changing the impersonation and authentication levels of the WMI connection, to no avail. Running this query in WbemTest shows no results or errors as well. Finally, I get the same results regardless of whether I use PowerShell or System.Management directly. Of course, the Google fails me here.

Can anyone give me some pointers on what I should try next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had lots of this sort of thing what i did was to make a function to run code on remote boxes,give it a try . Just change the computer name,username and password.

```
function remote-pscode ($ServerName,$UserName,$password,$PSCode)
{

# Set the user name you would like to use for the connection
$global:RemoteUserName = $UserName
$global:RemoteServerName = $ServerName
$global:RemoteCode = $PSCode

# Set the password you would like to use for the connection
# Check to see if you have a file on you drive c:\cred.txt with a password to use in it,if you don't it will create one
# for you and ask you for the password you would like to use 

$global:RemotePassword = convertto-securestring $password -AsPlainText -Force
$global:credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $RemoteUserName,$RemotePassword

#Create a connection to the remote computer , put a list of IPAddresses or Computer Names.
$global:session = new-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServerName -Credential $credentials

$ScriptBlock = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock($RemoteCode)

invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

#Close the sessions that where created     
$global:closesession = Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $closesession


$t = ($wmi_result = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT LogonId FROM Win32_LogonSession WHERE LogonType=2" 
 foreach ($obj in $wmi_result) 
 {$id = $obj.LogonId
  $user_list = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=$id} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" | Select Name
 })


remote-pscode -ServerName "testserver" -UserName "testserver\testuser" -password "testpassword" -PSCode "$t"
```